# Why isn't file_put_contents overwriting?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a page with a WYSIWYG editor the user can use. After editing, they can press a button, and the javascript should POST the current page to a save.php file and refresh the page with new information.

There are two problems. The first is that initially the page doesn't load with the updated file. The user has to refresh the page to see it updated (maybe it just takes an extra second to write the file?). The second problem, is that after the first time the temporary file was created, it cannot be overwritten, so the page never updates after the first refresh. Here are the snippets I'm working with:

Javascript function on the WYSIWYG editor page (editor.php):

```
function refresh(html,username,info)
{
    $.post("save.php", { html: html, username: username } );
    window.location = 'editor.php?info=' + info;
}
```

save.php file

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
$username = $_POST['username']; 
file_put_contents('temp/' . $username . '.txt', $html);
```

Comment: GAPING SECURITY HOLE! `username=../save.php%00` and `html=<?php something evil` will allow anyone to overwrite your php file and execute arbitrary code

Comment: Always sanitize your data properly. If you don't know how, please read a tutorial.

Comment: What permissions does the file have when it does get created?

Comment: I don't understand the security hole. The file being created would be .txt, how would you execute PHP on that?


The permissions on the file after it's created are 644, but even if I manually change them to 777 it still doesn't work.

Comment: @James: ThiefMaster either knows or assumes (I cannot confirm) that the filesystem functions are not binary-safe as far as the filename is concerned (i.e. parsing will stop at the first NUL byte). Therefore the `%00` will work much like `--` works in an SQL injection attack.

Comment: Exactly. PHP calls C functions such as `fopen()` or `open()` internally and their arguments are not binary-safe. So a null byte will terminate the filename. Besides that, `whatever.php.txt` would often still be executed as PHP by apache thanks to the way it handles extensions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I used htmlspecialchars() and it fixed the problem I was having with the data not saving the second time too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the browser may not have issued the POST request before navigating to the next page, use the success callback from the post to do the relocate:

```
function refresh(html,username,info) {
  $.post("save.php", { html: html, username: username }, function() {
    window.location = 'editor.php?info=' + info;
  });
}
```

As other people have already commented, using data directly from a form post without sanitising it is a really bad plan and opens your server up to all kinds of malicious attacks. Have a look at some of these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sanitize+php

If the data is getting to your server ok, make sure that the access permissions on the directory 'temp' allow write access from the web server user (if you have access to SSH to your server, run `chmod go+w /path/to/temp`, otherwise most FTP programs allow you to set file permissions too).

Answer (score 0):

why not use `fopen` and `fwrite`?

simply use:

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$file = "temp/" . $username . ".txt";

if (!file_exists($file)) {
  $files = fopen($file, "x+");
} else {
  $files = fopen($file, "w+");
}

if(fwrite($files, $html)) {
  echo "Success!";
} else {
  echo "Failure!";
}
```

for the php and to make the refresh work in js, try putting the statement in the success function like this:

```
function refresh(html,username,info) {
    $.post("save.php", { html: html, username: username }, 
            function (response) {
             window.location = 'editor.php?info=' + info;
             console.log(response);// for debugging :) 
           });
}
```

Comment: Why would `fopen` behave any differently than `file_put_contents`?

Comment: well `file_put_contents` isn't working, with the correct code, assuming the rest of his code that we can't see is correct, it seems logical to try `fopen`, it's never failed for me.

Comment: I tried fopen/fwrite as well, but with the same results. Thanks for the success function though.

Comment: @ChristopherKenney: It seems *anything but* logical to try `fopen`.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax request is asynchrone so the writing operation can be in progress when the redirection is started. You have to listen to the finished exent of the $.post action to do the redirect.